# How does Ellie know 18 hours passed?

Tags: contact

In Contact it appears as if Ellie blacks out for an unknown period of time. You can see what I'm talking about starting around 3:30 in this video.

If she really did black out how did her 18 hour estimation match so perfectly with the amount of static?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say "bad writing".

Comment: If I had to guess, she's been 'bought off'. In return for not mentioning the dodgy headset, she's been given a big fancy new radio telescope to play with.

Comment: The tape recorded static, but we have to indication there were no timers or watches, let alone ones that failed to operate. The tape recorded static, it didn't fail to work at all.

Comment: @CreationEdge - That's true, but then why did she say that there was no evidence? If she knew, she'd have mentioned it. If she didn't know, then how could she have come up with the figure of "18 hours"? Paradox.

Comment: In the book, there are five occupants and they have watches, so they are all aware of how much time passes for them while on their journey. In the novel, when Ellie mentions the relativistic differences seen in their watches vs ones on Earth, Kitz says "you've demolished my argument! I forgot that it's impossible to set your watch ahead by a day". The thing with her being aware of the time is, if not explicitly referenced in the film, likely a logical hold over from the novel